# Setting vm.max_map_count for mongodb with helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am successfully starting the mongodb with helm charts from bitnami. Also creating it as a replicaset. But it complains that the vm.max_map_count is too low. It seems like this is usually handled by an initContainer call. But I can't figure out how to do that with a helm chart.

Command used to start the replicaset

```
helm install mongodb-service oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/mongodb -f values.yaml --set architecture="replicaset"
```

This is the values part of the chart

```
initContainers: []
## @param sidecars Add additional sidecar containers for the MongoDB(&reg;) pod(s)
## Example:
## sidecars:
##   - name: your-image-name
##     image: your-image
##     imagePullPolicy: Always
##     ports:
##       - name: portname
##         containerPort: 1234
```

Example of setting the parameter on a non mongodb container.

```
containers:
      - name: sysctl
        image: busybox
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to bitnami helm chart description you just need to replace

```
initContainers: []
```

with

```
initContainers:
   - name: sysctl
     image: busybox
     command: ['sh', '-c', 'sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144']
```

in values.yaml reffered by

```
helm install mongodb-service oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/mongodb -f values.yaml --set architecture="replicaset
```